# how to add the accuracy circle to a MKAnnotation

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have a custom annotation to represent a moving bus, and id love to have that "pulse" has. I believe its also referred to as the accuracy circle. Is there a way to use that with an image overlay ontop of it?